# Sinatra assets doesn't work

Tags: ruby, sinatra, asset-pipeline

I have a Sinatra application where I have upgraded from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.4.3, after the upgrade assets are failing to load.

I have tried everything

```
22:25:32 application.1 | 10.191.228.114 - - [25/Mar/2018:22:25:32 -0700] "GET /assets//stylesheets/sso.css HTTP/1.0" 404 9 0.0076
22:25:32 application.1 | 10.191.228.114 - - [25/Mar/2018:22:25:32 -0700] "GET /assets//javascripts/login.js HTTP/1.0" 404 9 0.0061
22:25:32 application.1 | 10.191.228.114 - - [25/Mar/2018:22:25:32 -0700] "GET /assets//javascripts/login.js HTTP/1.0" 404 9 0.0079
```

Below is the code, please correct me if  I am doing anything wrong here.

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sprockets'
require 'sprockets-helpers'
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline'
require 'compass'

helpers Sprockets::Helpers

set :app_root, File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/../../")
set :public_folder, File.join(app_root + "/public")
assets = %w(login.js sso.css *.png *.jpg *.gif views/invitations/signup_form.js)
locale_files = Dir[File.join(app_root, 'config', 'locales', '*.yml')]

set :scss,                  {:style => :compact, :debug_info => true}
set :assets_precompile,     assets
set :assets_paths,          %w(app/assets vendor/assets)
set :assets_prefix,         %w(app/assets vendor/assets)
set :assets_css_compressor, :sass
set :assets_js_compressor, :uglifier
set :session_secret, "something secret, something safe"

register Sinatra::AssetPipeline
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Did your sinatra version stay the same? Are you using bundler with a Gemfile.lock and did that change?

Comment: Ya Sinatra version is same 1.4. 
I have deleted the Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sinatra/asset_pipeline and consider that the best place to start debugging. Are other assets, stored in /public, those not created by some asset-pipeline, but simple, static files, served correct?

Comment: The assets are stored in app/assets, not in public.